# In Microsoft Bot Framework session.conversationData.array of regexes changes to array of Object type after executing once

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am working with the below piece of code in Microsoft Bot Framework to access the list of regexes for global commands. This code is a part of botbuilder module:

```
if (typeof session.conversationData.globalCommands === "undefined") {
    // An array which contains the list of all global commands
    session.conversationData.globalCommands = [];
    // Accessing the list of global commands
    globalActions = session.library.actions.actions;
    lenGlobalActions = Object.keys(globalActions).length;
    // Assigning values to the above list
    for (var i=0; i<lenGlobalActions; i++){
        session.conversationData.globalCommands.push(globalActions[Object.keys(globalActions)[i]].options.matches);
    }
}
// Checking if the incoming message from the user is a global command
var isGlobalCommand = session.conversationData.globalCommands.some(regex => regex.test(session.message.text));
```

The issue here is, the code runs fine for the first time and the values assigned to the variable session.conversationData.globalCommands are in the form given below: [image: Valid array]

However, after the first execution, the array converts to the below without any changes made in the code anywhere else:
[image: invalid array]

Due to this, the line:

```
var isGlobalCommand = session.conversationData.globalCommands.some(regex => regex.test(session.message.text));
```

throws an exception "regex.test is not a function".

I am unable to understand why this should be happening and how do I solve this as I need this list separately for some processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot store complex types in the bot store (conversationData, etc). The object needs to be serializable to JSON and I don't believe a RegExp it is.

The workaround would be to store the regex as an string and then recreate the regex object using the constructor and the stored string expression.

Check the [core-State](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-State) sample to know more about the store capabilities.