# Botframework (Node) - dialogData stripping out regex

Tags: node.js, botframework

Does the BotBuilder Node SDK actively strip out anything that is stored the `dialogData` object?

For example, I have created a simple loop and I am storing a regex in `session.dialogData.questions`. When I console log this after storing it, I can see that my regex is stored as expected:

```
  { 
    validation: /^[0-9]{19}$/,
  }
```

However, when I try and log the same `session.dialogData.questions` object in the next step of my waterfall, then the regex seems to have been converted into an empty object:

```
  {
    validation: {}
  }
```

I presume this a deliberate attempt to prevent XSS and other types of exploitation?

The code for this example can be found below:

```
const builder = require('botbuilder')
const lib = new builder.Library('FormBuilder')

lib.dialog('/', [
    (session, args) => {
      session.dialogData.questions = {
        validation: /^[0-9]{19}$/
      }
      console.log(session.dialogData.questions)
      builder.Prompts.confirm(session, 'Would you like to proceed?')
    },
    (session, results) => {
      console.log(session.dialogData.questions)
    }
])

module.exports.createLibrary = () => {
  return lib.clone()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Microsoft Bot Framework session.conversationData.array of regexes changes to array of Object type after executing once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926866/in-microsoft-bot-framework-session-conversationdata-array-of-regexes-changes-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your initial question, no the SDK doesn't actively strip anything out of the dialogData object. Anything that is, except for regexp...

I'm not sure why this is, but for the time being I recommend storing your pattern as a string, `'^[0-9]{19}$'`, and then constructing a new regexp via `new RegExp(session.dialogData.questions.validation)` when needed.

I tried storing a method to construct a new RegExp using `this.questions.validation`, but likewise this was also stripped out.

---

#### Edit:

Per Ezequiel's comment, this isn't a Bot Framework issue in the end. It is not possible to store non-serializable data inside JSON.

Comment: Thanks Steven. That was going to be my plan as well, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious!

Comment: No problem :) Hopefully I or someone will be able to elaborate on the subject in the near future (or perhaps even change the answer)

Comment: RegExp is not serializable to JSON and thus won't be stored. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926866/in-microsoft-bot-framework-session-conversationdata-array-of-regexes-changes-to)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up Ezequiel! @tombraider storing it as a string is the way to go :)